# Проблема с onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Есть `activity`, в нем `ViewPager` и `FloatingActionButton`. Я получаю ссылку на `fab` во фрагментах `view pager` и ставлю на нее `onClickListener`,
каждый фрагмент содержит уникальный `id`, который нужно обрабатывать в `onClickListener`.
Проблема заключается в том, что в обработчике значение `id` всегда `null`, хотя в `onCreate` фрагмента присваивается значение и в логах все показывает.
Перепробовал разные варианты, и всегда переменная `null` в обработчике.
Дело в том, что переменную сделать`static` не могу потому, что ломается логика, и `FloatingActionButton` не могу поместить во фрагменты, она должна быть в активности.
Есть ли выход в данной ситуации?

Comment: Код, относящийся к вопросу показывайте - нам неизвестно что и как Вы делаете. Если на FAB должен реагировать активный фрагмент, нужно вешать обработчик в нём в момент активации (надо смотреть жизненный цикл, на память не скажу)

Comment: А почему не прописать функцию с одним именем в каждом фрагменте и просто вызывать ее для текущего фрагмента по нажатию `fab`?

Comment: Код скину через пару часов. Значение переменной в этой функции будет null, из-за того, что fab находиться в активности, я так понимаю. Сейчас фрагменты наследуються от абстрактного фрагмента и реализуют абстрактный метод getId(), он вызывается в обработчике и возвращает null. Если его вызвать в onCreate когда isUserVisibleHint = true значение соответствует ожидаемому, а в обработчике всегда null и isUserVisibleHint = false всегда.

Comment: Решил проблему, спасибо за комментарии!